# Segmentation fault 11 modsecurity?

Tags: php, segmentation-fault, strlen

If I disable mod security module it fixes segmentation faults problem. Problem occur on php script which actually saves some configuration to file.

What this backtrack log is saying?
Where I should be searching?

```
[New Thread 10273]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Core was generated by `/usr/sbin/httpd'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x000003e307a55d70 in strlen () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 1 (Thread 0x3e3099ec760 (LWP 10273)):
#0  0x000003e307a55d70 in strlen () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x000003e308161c18 in apr_vformatter () from /usr/lib64/libapr-1.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x000003e30816bd49 in apr_pvsprintf () from /usr/lib64/libapr-1.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x000003e30816bfa8 in apr_psprintf () from /usr/lib64/libapr-1.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x000003e2fef4eb75 in apr_sockaddr_ip_get ()
   from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_security2.so
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x000003e2fef515b1 in apr_sockaddr_ip_get ()
   from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_security2.so
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x000003e2fef6cf74 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_security2.so
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x000003e2fef44640 in apr_sockaddr_ip_get ()
   from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_security2.so
No symbol table info available.
#8  0x00000040b23781ca in ap_run_fixups ()
No symbol table info available.
#9  0x00000040b238ae18 in ap_process_request ()
No symbol table info available.
#10 0x00000040b2388010 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#11 0x00000040b2384112 in ap_run_process_connection ()
No symbol table info available.
#12 0x00000040b238f2c9 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#13 0x00000040b238f55a in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#14 0x00000040b238f610 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#15 0x00000040b23902fb in ap_mpm_run ()
No symbol table info available.
#16 0x00000040b2369fd8 in main ()
No symbol table info available.
```

yum --nogpgcheck --enablerepo=debug install httpd-debuginfo installed debug but along with httpd there is no symbols installed, how to install them ?